# switch case menu and nsstring uppercase

Tags: menu, nsstring, switch-statement, uppercase

Basically this is a switch case menu program. I'm  put the enter a string functions before the menu part to keep it organized. My main issue at the moment is case 4. What I'm trying to do is make a function that converts a whole string into uppercase. But i can't seem to find a way to apply it to the entered string. It only works if i define a predetermined string.

```
const int CSTR_MAX = 33;        

void readCString(char cs[])
{
printf("Enter a character string up to %i characters:  ", CSTR_MAX-1);
scanf("%s", cs);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {

    char cstr[CSTR_MAX];
    int choices;
    BOOL done=FALSE;         
    NSString *obj;
    NSString *uppercase = (Imnotsurewhatneedstogohere);
    NSString *lowercase;

    readCString(cstr);

    do {
        //Print the menu and prompt the use for the selection
        printf("\nMenu Choices\n");
        printf("------------\n");
        printf("1) Enter a new string\n");
        printf("4) Change all letters to Upper Case\n");
        printf("5) Change all letters to lower case\n");
        printf("8) Quit");
        printf("\nEnter your choices: ");
        scanf("%i", &choices);


        switch(choices)
        {
            case 1:
                //Enter a new String
                readCString(cstr);

                break;

            case 4:
                //Change all letters to Upper Case
                obj = [uppercase uppercaseString];
                NSLog(@"Uppercase conversion: %s", [uppercase UTF8String]);
                break;

            case 5:
                //Change all letters to lower case
                obj = [lowercase lowercaseString];
                NSLog (@"Lowercase conversion: %@", obj);
                break;



            case 8:
                //Quit
                break;
            default:  printf("You entered an invalid choice\n");
                done = TRUE;

        }

    } while (!done);

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you parse this down to the relevant code and clearly clarify what it is that's not working?

Comment: add int counter                                                                  counter = 0;
                           while(cstr[counter] != ' ')
                           {
                               if(cstr[counter] > 96)
                                   cstr[counter] = cstr[counter] - 32;
                               counter++;
                           }
                           printf("%s\n", cstr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason why you are experiencing this issue it because you are NSLoging `[uppercase UTF8String]` which you never set the the new uppercase value. You should use  `NSLog(@"Uppercase conversion: %s", [obj UTF8String]);` because obj is set to the uppercase conversion, or rename your variables.

So case 4 should look like this:

```
case 4:
                //Change all letters to Upper Case
                obj = [uppercase uppercaseString];
                NSLog(@"Uppercase conversion: %s", [obj UTF8String]);
                break;
```

Comment: Right, well im trying to set the uppercase value to the entered string. so that when the string is typed in and the option is selected it will make the whole string uppercase. But I'm not sure what the value has to be to accomplish that.

Comment: ah, that helps. Do you think i should set  NSString *uppercase =  to something or not?

Comment: It's entirely up to you. If you want you can replace `obj` with `uppercase`

Comment: I will, I'm just trying to figure out this last part. my issue is more with the (  NSString *uppercase = ) part. usually after the = there is a string defined with @"example string" and thats what would have its case changed. So it would be EXAMPLE STRING. But instead i want that to equal the text inputed so that whatever text i type each time can be modified with the different options.

Comment: I actually got it       i just added int counter at the top then put this in case 4              counter = 0;
                           while(cstr[counter] != ' ')
                           {
                               if(cstr[counter] > 96)
                                   cstr[counter] = cstr[counter] - 32;
                               counter++;
                           }
                           printf("%s\n", cstr);

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. Usually you would just create a new variable and than copy the string into other variables.